# ASP .NET C# Lto ink ListItems in DropDownList to row items in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, drop-down-menu

I'm using a `GridView` and `SqlDataSource` but I would like to display different names in the dropdownlist but have it be associated with a database. For example, I would like to have the dropdownlist say "All Stores" but in the database it's stored as "ALL". Is this possible? Thanks :)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit" SortExpression="BUSN_UNIT_CD">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="BUSN_UNIT_DS" 
                    DataValueField="BUSN_UNIT_DS">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:jobCodeConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [BUSN_UNIT_DS] FROM [BUSN_UNIT]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The DropDownList is stored within the GridView.

Comment: What is the connection between your GridView and DropDownlist? Is DropDownList within GridView? And yes it  is possible to have dropdownlist say "All Stores" but in the database it's stored as "ALL". **It will be better if you post some code that you tried ?**

Comment: @RojalinSahoo The DropDownList is in the GridView in a TemplateField as an ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use different values and different text, pass the value to database(All).

```
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" Width="200px">
            <asp:ListItem Text="All Stores" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="ONE Store" Value="ONE"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Two Store" Value="TWO"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

"Text" will be seen in UI but the value can be passed to datasource or database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

Insert first the record from db to gridview then load data to dropdown like this;

```
DataTable dt = querytodbHere_Return_DataTable; 
 DropDownList lst = new DropDownList();
 foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
   {
    lst = (DGGeneric.Rows[cnt].Cells[0].FindControl("drpaction") as DropDownList);
    lst.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Action--"));
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
     lst.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[1].ToString()));                              
    }    
     cnt += 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am trying using linq expression here i'm union all first one fixed record with database all records.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dllist" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**CS:**

```
DataTable dt = your_data_source;
var i = (from j in new string[] { "" }
                 select new
                 {
                     TEXT = "All Stores",
                     VALUE = "ALL",
                 }).AsEnumerable().Union(from k in dt.AsEnumerable()
         select new { TEXT = k.Field<string>("TEXT"), VALUE = k.Field<string>("VALUE") });
    dllist.DataSource = i;
    dllist.DataValueField = "VALUE";
    dllist.DataTextField = "TEXT";
    dllist.DataBind();
```

i hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

So here are the suggestions you could try:

**Method 1:**
Manipulate your Database Value in query like:

```
 Select DISTINCT CASE [BUSN_UNIT_DS] WHEN 'ALL' THEN 'ALL STORE' ELSE [BUSN_UNIT_DS] END FROM [BUSN_UNIT]
```

**Method 2:**
Use DataBound Method to alter your Value of DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="BUSN_UNIT_DS" 
  DataValueField="BUSN_UNIT_DS" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
  OnDataBound="DropDownList5_DataBound">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void DropDownList5_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddltype = (DropDownList)sender;
    foreach (ListItem item in ddltype .Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == "ALL")
        {
            item.Text = "ALL STORE";
        }
    }
}
```